# Precise definition of Universal Learner in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, learning-theory

It is surprising to me that I cannot find a precise definition of universal learner on the internet. I can guess what it should bebut I don't want to make a mistake, therefore I have come here.

Here's how I think it should be:

*A learning algorithm is said to be a universal learner if there exists a function $m:(0,1)^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ such that the following holds:
For every $(\epsilon,\delta) \in (0,1)^2$ and for every labelled domain set $\mathscr{X}$x$\mathscr{Y}$ with a distribution D over it, if $m>m(\epsilon,\delta)$ iid samples are taken then the algorithm spits out a hypothesis h such that with probability at least $1-\delta$, we have $L_D(h)<\epsilon$*

Is this definition correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by a universal learner, but if you mean a kind of learner who has no prior knowledge about a certain task and is ready to challenged by any task, then, as far as I know, no such learner exists. (See the book of Understanding of Machine Learning by Shai Shalev Shwartz chapter 5)

Comment: yes I mean that. But my point is, to know something doesn't exist, we must know what exactly that entity is. Which is not clear to me. @Doralisa

Comment: If you had take a look at the book I've introduced, then it could be clear for you. In the page 60, we have this: *A specific learning task is defined by an unknown
distribution $D$ over $X \times Y$, where the goal of the learner is to find a predictor
$h : X \rightarrow Y$, whose risk, $L_D(h)$, is small enough. The question is therefore whether there exist a learning algorithm $A$ and a training set size $m$, such that for every distribution $D$, if $A$ receives $m$ i.i.d. examples from $D$, there is a high chance it outputs a predictor $h$ that has a low risk.*

Comment: Also, if you go further in this chapter you may see the No Free Lunch Theorem that states that for every learner, there exists a task on which it fails, even though the task can be successfully learned by another learner.

Comment: @Doralisa I am following that book for my semester so I have seen that piece of text before. But I am not quite satisfied with it since it is very hand-wavy.